# How do I conditional format based on the set of cells above the cell in question?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to implement a system that tracks progress with building and improving on a habit. I would like a visual representation on how that is going, and am using conditional formatting to achieve this.

As it currently is:

- **Pale green** `=b2=b1` (Same as yesturday)
- **Green** `=b2>b1` (Better than yesturday)
- **Red** `=b2<b1` (Worse than yesturday)

I would like an **Orange** colour to show when the number is better than yesturday but not better than the previous best. The problem with my current condition is it looks at the entire range, rather than just what is above it.

`=and(B2>B1, (B2<max(b1:B100)))`

This needs to become somthing like:

`=and(B2>B1, (B2<max(B1:B[CURRENT CELL NUMBER])))`

So how do I get this 'current cell number'?

Example of what I'm looking for:

[image: Image of the desired outcome]

Comment: @player0 I have included an image

Comment: Dan, first figure out the order of rules so that the overriding rule will be entered first and so on. Then write a rule for each condition. Lastly go into the Manage Rules menu and check the "Stop if True" box. That way once a rule is matched no further rules will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to anchor the top of the range and the current cell will adjust by relative addressing:

```
=and(B2>B1, B2<max(B$1:B1))
```

[image]

I have filled columns C to F in to check that the formulas are working correctly. Note that the Orange rule has to fire before the Green rule. I haven't formatted B1 because there is nothing to compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

top to bottom:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(B:B, B1, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B1)))=1

=(B1=MAX(B$1:B1))

=(B1>B2)*(B2)

=(B1<>"")
```

note the offset for red